# What does the function of .a means in a beautifulsoup element?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to understand the code of [this](http://web.stanford.edu/~zlotnick/TextAsData/Web_Scraping_with_Beautiful_Soup.html) post,

In line In[10],

```
lobbying = {}
for element in letters:
    lobbying[element.a.get_text()] = {}
```

Basically, "element" is an element in the BeatifulSoup object letters, I don't understand what's the function of .a following element. Though I want to find answer by my own, I have no idea how to find such little thing.

Answer (score 4):

BeautifulSoup lets you search for tags by using them as attribute names. `element.a` simply is a short-cut for `element.find('a')`.

See the [*Navigating using tag names* section](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names) in the documentation:

> The simplest way to navigate the parse tree is to say the name of the
>   tag you want. If you want the `<head>` tag, just say `soup.head`:
>
> ```
> soup.head
> # <head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
>
> soup.title
> # <title>The Dormouse's story</title>
> ```